# How do I extend text selection bar?

Tags: android, textview, share

How can I achieve this :

When I select text I want the bar to show not only "copy" ,"select all" and "confirm"
but also a "share" icon like on a screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a look at [setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback%28android.view.ActionMode.Callback%29)

Then in your custom ActionMode.Callback, can fetch the selected text with:

```
int start = myTextView.getSelectionStart();
int end = myTextView.getSelectionEnd();
```